# Pass Facebook SDK session to webview

Tags: android, authentication, webview, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have Facebook SDK integrated in my android app, with login button, which is working perfectly and everything else is fine. I need to add webview to make like button, but it says I'm logged out and Facebook SDK session doesn't make any difference. I mean, if I log in using  Facebook SDK, webview still shows I'm logged out. So, how can I pass Facebook SDK session to webview session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such way to share your android hosted access token from session with `webview` context, you can look  that duplicated question about it. [`Share session facebook SDK with webview`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324195/how-to-login-into-facebook-in-webview-if-already-have-access-token-from-fb-sdk-i)

Comment: not sure of that, in buzzfeed app if you are logged with facebook in the app, the facebook comments plugin they use embedded in a webview has the user session

Answer (score 1):

1. Login with LoginBehavior.SURPRESS_SSO, which uses a web dialog for Facebook login. After this, WebView has an active Facebook session. I've tried with Facebook SDK v4.1.0.

   loginButton.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);

   or

   loginManager.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
2. As others mentioned, pass token to WebView through JavaScript interface or URL query.
3. Did you use WebView just for like-button? It is available for Android since 3.19.0. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#buttons